# Install Yii2 extension manually without using Composer giving error of class not found

Tags: yii2, widget, composer-php

I want to install [2amigos/yii2-google-maps-library](https://github.com/2amigos/yii2-google-maps-library) widget Manually.

I have added `"2amigos/yii2-google-maps-library" : "*"` in required section of `composer.json` and I have added `'dosamigos\\google\\maps\\' => array($vendorDir . '/2amigos/yii2-google-maps-library'),` in `composer autoload_psr4.php`

I have added `'2amigos/yii2-google-maps-library' => 
  array (
    'name' => '2amigos/yii2-google-maps-library',
    'alias' => 
    array (
      '@dosamigos\google\maps' => $vendorDir . '2amigos/yii2-google-maps-library',
    ),
  ),` code in extensions.php of composer.
And my view code is

```
<?php

    use dosamigos\google\maps\LatLng;
    use dosamigos\google\maps\services\DirectionsWayPoint;
    use dosamigos\google\maps\services\TravelMode;
    use dosamigos\google\maps\overlays\PolylineOptions;
    use dosamigos\google\maps\services\DirectionsRenderer;
    use dosamigos\google\maps\services\DirectionsService;
    use dosamigos\google\maps\overlays\InfoWindow;
    use dosamigos\google\maps\overlays\Marker;
    use dosamigos\google\maps\Map;
    use dosamigos\google\maps\services\DirectionsRequest;
    use dosamigos\google\maps\overlays\Polygon;
    use dosamigos\google\maps\layers\BicyclingLayer;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
$this->title = Yii::$app->name;
?>
<section>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">

            <?php 
                $coord = new LatLng(['lat' => 39.720089311812094, 'lng' => 2.91165944519042]);
                $map = new Map([
                    'center' => $coord,
                    'zoom' => 14,
                ]);
             ?>

        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

But when i run this give me error

```
Class 'dosamigos\google\maps\LatLng' not found
```

Comment: "2amigos/yii2-google-maps-library" is the downloaded folder on correct path  i.e vendor/2amigos/yii2-google-maps-library ?

Comment: yes it is in correct folder.

Answer (score 0):

Oh thanks got finally I got my solution. I added namespace with backslashes that cause error. I fixed

```
'2amigos/yii2-google-maps-library' => 
  array (
    'name' => '2amigos/yii2-google-maps-library',
    'version' => '9999999-dev',
    'alias' => 
    array (
      '@dosamigos/google/maps' => $vendorDir . '/2amigos/yii2-google-maps-library',
    ),
  ),
```

in extensions.php